# Android singleTask activity background problem

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activites. `Activity A` and `Activity B`.

`Activity A` is a singleTask activity. `Activity B` has no extra configuration. So it is a normal activity.

When `Activity A` launches the `activity B` then if user presses to the home button then comes back immediately (so my app is not killed by android yet.) My app is showing `activity A`. But it should show the `activity B` because the user pressed to home button when active activity is B.

If i remove the singleTask property from Activity A. It is working as expected. But i have to use singleTask activity for some other reason.

How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: have you tried with singleTop

Comment: https://medium.com/@iammert/android-launchmode-visualized-8843fc833dbe

Comment: @Tolgay Toklar : Can you check my answer, whether it worked for you or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have constraint to use `singleTask` launch mode, you can do following :

1. When user press `Home`, app or `Activity B` goes in background (`stopped state`)
2. Then when you open app, it'll show `Activity A` because of `singleTask` launch mode
3. In `Activity A`, **override** `onNewIntent()` method. This will get called from android os. You can fire `Activity B`'s intent from this method. So, system will open `Activity A` when coming from background to your app, but from this method, `Activity B` would be shown.

I've edited my answer to handle below scenario :

- If we're on `ActivityA`, we press **Home** button and we come back, `ActivityA` should be shown, not `ActivityB`. To do this, I used `boolean` `shouldOpenB`

in **Activity A** :

```
static boolean shouldOpenB = false;

// set shouldOpenB to true when you are opening ActivityB from your code with Intent

// reset shouldOpenB to false in onStart() of AcrivityA

protected void onNewIntent (Intent intent) {
    if(shouldOpenB) {
        Intent openIntentB = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(openIntentB);
    }
}
```

Note : The animation of `Activity A` -> `Activity B` would be visible to user for fraction of time. If you agree to change to `singleTop`, we can remove this animation also.